# Eloquent Model, Illegal offset type error on non-date field

Tags: laravel, attributes, eloquent

When I try to create a UserFailedLogin object I get an illegal offset type error. When I look closer the it appears to be trying to cast the ip address column to a date. The column is not a date in the DB nor is it in the $date of the model.

Here is my Model:

```
class UserFailedLogin extends Model {

public $timestamps = false;
protected $table = 'user_failed_login';
protected $fillable = ['ip','email'];
protected $primaryKey = ['invalid_login_id'];
```

Here is my create statement:

```
UserFailedLogin::create(['ip' => $request->ip(), 'email'=>$email,]);
```

My Error:

> ErrorException in Model.php line 2759:
>
> Illegal offset type
>
> 1. in Model.php lne 2759
> 2. at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'Illegal offset type', '.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php',
>      '2759', array()) in Model.php line 2759
> 3. at Model->getCasts() in Model.php line 2743
> 4. at Model->hasCast('ip', array('date', 'datetime')) in Model.php line 2774
> 5. at Model->isDateCastable('ip') in Model.php line 2863

Answer (score 5):

I think the issue is that your primary key is an array instead of just a string.

Try changing that to be:
`protected $primaryKey = 'invalid_login_id';`

The getCasts is looking for a string and not an array or object.

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurred because the eloquent thinks your primary key is a composite primary key, cause you added it to array, in your case just make the primary key a string, in the really composite primary keys you should use ["Mass Updates"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#updates). I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

`->ip()` is not a function, is it a member accessor, it should be `->ip` or `->get('ip')`. That is to say, unless you've create a custom `Request` class which implements the `IP` function, although I do not see that being the case given your stack trace.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review my issue. The ->ip() does return my ip address but regardless it is not the issue. I still get the error when I hardcoded in the value instead of making the call to any ip functions. (In fact in both cases my ip is displayed in the stack track.)